# Is there a way to access primary key created on SaveChanges() from the DbModelBuilder modelBuilder (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have a property that is based on the entity id. So I am trying to avoid the following code:

```
dbContext.SaveChanges();
entyty.propertyInQuestion = SomeFunkyMethod(entity.Id)
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

So the idea is not to override SaveChanges() but to put the SomeFunkyMethod somewhere the Fluent API. My best guess so far was to do it in the ValueGenerator but it seems that it is designed for different purposes.

Comment: What does SomeFunkyMethod do?

Comment: It generates a string value based on mathematical transformations on the id.

Comment: Is the generated id auto-incremental?

Comment: Yes, the id is auto-incremental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use EF for this, then the answer is somewhere between "no" and "badly".

What about creating a DB trigger that updates the property after insert?

(depending on your DB subsystem, postgres here)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION some_funky_method() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN

    -- whatever implemenation of your logic
    NEW."UpdatedProperty" := NEW."Id" * 666;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_property_on_insert
AFTER INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE some_funky_method();
```

---

UPDATE

There is no way doing this with EntityFramework and auto-incremented Ids. The Id is generated by DB sequence at the time of insert and that's the point. If you cannot use a trigger, any other solution would be only a ugly hack resulting in second database call at some point.

Of course, you could predict the Id with querying the sequence state, but that's generally a very bad idea.

However, there is one other option, if you have the possibility - change the primary key from INT to **GUID**.
At this point you can generate the Id by yourself and use it for anything *before* the insert.

```cs
public class MyEntity {
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string SomethingElse { get; set; }
   (...)
}
entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
entity.SomethingElse = /* Do something with the Id */ entity.Id.ToString();
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That is lovely however I am a little bit restricted and i was wandering if between the "no" and "badly" there is a way ? I am gonna mark this as an accepted answer as it indeed makes what I was asking about.

Comment: @TodorPopov I've been thinking about it and there is IMHO not any other "clean" solution with EF. I updated the answer for details.